# Dynamic load a 3d model from a file located in a webserver

Tags: xcode, file, opengl, webserver

I will like to make an App that will display a 3d model from a file.

I know already to create an App that display a 3d model like a banana which is part of the App in a .h header file.

But I will like to do is to make a small list of 3d objects to display in the App and when the user choose a model it will be uploaded from the local webserver into the phone and then the phone render it.

What I do no know what to do is to do the dynamic programming that load the 3d model and display it.

---

I have done a test, I have edited with the WordPad in Windows on my Local Webserver a file banana.h which contains a list of float arrays in order to extract one array and create a text file named ObjVerts.txt

I have done a lot of search in the Web in order to find a small piece of code that can read the text file and convert it to a float array but I did not find any.

I have found a lot of piece of code that read the file and make a NSSMutuableData but many of the code seem to not work.

It seem that the last statement return nothing!

Please I would appreciate if you can guide me a bit more.

Here the piece of code I did try :

```
    NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
                                                          URLWithString:@"http://localhost/ObjVerts.txt"]

                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0]

    NSURLConnection *connection2=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request2 delegate:self];

    if (connection2)
    {
        NSMutableData *response2 = [[NSMutableData data2] retain];

        glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*) response2);

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Could not create connection");
    }
```

thanks Regis

---

This works and return me some data but I do not know how to transform the result to a GLfloat array:

```
    NSURL *myurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/ObjVerts.txt"];
    NSData *mystring = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myurl];
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*) mystring[0]);
```

thanks Regis

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a FAQ. But well:

Loading a 3D model from a file or a web resource works just like loading any data.

1. open
2. read
3. parse

Steps 2 and 3 may happen in staggered batches. For example for some file types you need to read and parse few lines first, to know what to read next.

If you want to load it from a webserver, you must talk the HTTP protocol. Since implementing this is a tedious task, there exist ready to use libraries, like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), soing the job for you.

The details of the parsing process depend on the used file format. But the result will be data in your process address space, just as if it was a static array constant you linked in from a .h, and you use it like that then.

Comment: thanks, but if someone can just help me a bit more please it would be appreciated. I did found this demo : http://code.google.com/p/iphonewavefrontloader/source/checkout which does what I want to do but this one load the 3d model locally. What need to adjusted so it load the file from my local webserver ? I think that the work need to be done here OpenGLWaveFrontObject.m and the section to be worked is i think this one : - (id)initWithPath:(NSString *)path
{
 if ((self = [super init]))
 {
  self.sourceObjFilePath = path;
  NSString *objData2 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path];

Comment: @user1961175: I already pointed you to libcurl, which does all the heavy lifting for you (i.e. talking to the webserver, downloading a resource, etc.). Resources on a webserver can not be accessed like regular files. You first must download them into some kind of buffer. Doesn't have to be a file.

Comment: ok thanks, do I need to start another question. Because what I do not know now, is how to convert the data that I did received as NSData to a GLFloat array ? Thanks Regis

Comment: @user1961175: That second step would involve parsing some fileformat. Something I can recommend is representing the data in JSON format, which is easy to parse and very flexible. You need to settle to a fileformat before doing further steps. Please do not send raw data over a network, as it opens your program to security threats. Everything coming from a network should be treated suspiciously and undergo several integrity checks.